# Show/Hide Div as Overlay

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility

I am trying to create image overlays which can toggle on and off by clicking a button. Basically I have one main image then I want to click button A and have overlay  A show up over the main image and click button B and have overlay A go away and show overlay B.

Currently I am trying to do this by creating a hidden div which has a background image on it. The current code works for the first button listed but not for any of the others.

```
<div class="hide schoolContent" id="schools"

</div>

<div class ="hide recreationContent" id="recreation">

</div>


<div class="hide restaurantsContent"id="restaurants">

</div>


<div class="hide banksContent" id="banks">

</div>


<div class="hide groceriesContent"id="groceries">

</div>


<div class="hide transportationContent"id="transportation">

</div>


<div class="hide libraryContent" id="library"></div>

<div>

<button  class="alertName" name="schoolContent">Schools</button>

<button  class="alertName" name="recreationContent">Recreation</button>

<button  class="alertName" name="restaurantsContent">Restaurants</button>

<button  class="alertName" name="banksContent">Banks</button>

<button  class="alertName" name="groceriesContent">Groceries</button>

<button  class="alertName" name="transportationContent">Study Transportation</button>

<button  class="alertName" name="libraryContent">Library</button>
</div>


<script>var alertName = document.getElementsByClassName("alertName");

var myFunction = function() {

var hide = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");

for (var i =< 0; i < hide.length; i++) {

hide[i].style.display = "none";

}

var name = this.getAttribute("name");

var show = document.querySelector('.' + name);

if (show.style.display = "none") {

show.style.display = "block";

}

else {

show.style.display = "none";

}

};

for (var i = 0; i < alertName.length; i++) {

alertName[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction);

}</script>
```

Comment: The code seems fine - maybe it's the missing **>** at the end of `<div class="hide schoolContent" id="schools"`

Comment: Yet another mistake in the loop init: `for (var i =< 0; i < hide.length; i++)` : `var i` sould be initialized with 0: `var i = 0`. I think it's a reason of issue

Comment: It could be easier to help you if you append relevant css rules to question

Comment: @Banzay thanks for letting me know about the css, I am new posting here and didn't know how much code to share.